# Is there missing information to answer this question!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations

I have two quantities $A_1$ and $A_2$, and I would like to compare them in order to know which one is bigger.

Knowing that $x$, $y$ are two constants such that $y \leq \frac{x}{2}$

$$A_1 = \sum_{z=1}^y (x-y+z)!(y-z+1)! (z+1)$$

$$A_2 = \sum_{z=1}^y (x-y+z+2)! (y-z)! (z+3)$$

Simply I want to specify if $A_1 > A_2$ or $A_1 < A_2$ ?

*I guess that we can say $A_1 > A_2$ $n$ increases because the factorial increases faster, but which constraints I should put here?*

Comment: $A_1$ and $A_2$ don't depend on $z$ so I have no idea what you mean by comparing them when $z=y$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Certainly, the question is not for $z=y$ but, as I don't have an idea how to solve the question,  I compared at the maximum value of $z$. Is there an idea how to answer?

Comment: You are not understanding me: $z$ is the dummy variable of the summation, all you are doing is pulling out one term. Personally I would start off with the sums starting at $z=0$, and divide everything by $x!$ and then see if I could express this in terms of binomial coefficients.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am sorry, I don't understand you! I don't have sums starting at $z=0$ and I you don't see why to divide over $x!$

Comment: $\frac y2 \ge z > 0$ contradicts $z=y$.

Comment: @pH74 Thanks, I modified it.

Comment: I'd start with looking at some small examples, like $y = 2$, $x = 5$ and variations thereof

Comment: You may not have sums starting at $0$, but putting them in makes the sums sensible, and the new sums only differ from the ones you have by a controllable term. I think that if you put this problem in context it might help see what's going on. Where did $A_1$ and $A_2$ spring from?

Answer (score 1):

We have $x-y\ge y.$ So, for each given $z,$ the ratio of the "$z$-term" in $A_2$ to the "$z$-term" in $A_1$ is $$\frac {((x-y)+z+2)((x-y)+z+1)}{y-z+1}\cdot \frac {z+3}{z+1}\ge \frac {(y+z+2)(y+z+1)}{y-z+1}\cdot \frac {z+3}{z+1}=$$ $$=(y+z+2)\cdot  \frac {(y+1)+z}{(y+1)-z}\cdot \frac {z+3}{z+1}>$$ $$>(y+z+2)\cdot 1 \cdot 1\ge 4.$$ So $A_2>4A_1>0.$